# android : Invalid authorisation header in http get response

Tags: android, http-headers, authorization, httpresponse, microsoft-band

I have tried all possible ways to get correct JSON response from the below microsoft health API url. But its always giving me the "Invalid Authorisation Request" in the JSON response. I have tried Base64 encoding of authorisation token also but its not responding. I don't know where i am going wrong ?

```
String authToken="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";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                        request.setURI(new URI("https://api.microsofthealth.net/v1/me/Summaries/Daily?startTime=" + startTime + "&endTime=" + endTime));
                        String authString = "Bearer " + authToken;
                        request.addHeader("Authorization", authString);

                        response = client.execute(request);

                        String json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: How did you get the access token?

Comment: Your token does not look valid (e.g. it's not nearly as long as the tokens I get via the OAuth flow).

Comment: @BNK I got the access token from authentication flow as specified in the API docs http://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/MS%20Health%20API%20Getting%20Started.pdf

Comment: What scopes do you request when obtaining the token?

Comment: Thanks all for you comments It was not working because of wrong date time format. Its working fine now. I am using these three scopes (offline_access mshealth.ReadDevices mshealth.ReadActivityHistory) but i am also not able to get the refresh token for the scope offline_access. Should i change any settings in my microsoft account ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the access token again to make sure it's valid. Because I use the new token in your question, reponse still 401.

```
GET https://api.microsofthealth.net/v1/me/Profile/
Authorization: bearer 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

 -- response --
401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Pragma:  no-cache
Expires:  -1
Server:  Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate:  Bearer realm="mshealth" error="invalid_token"
X-AspNet-Version:  4.0.30319
AppEx-Activity-Id:  7c22cdab-5307-4b62-b81b-42e1315d9b1b
x-powered-by:  ASP.NET
Date:  Mon, 31 Aug 2015 07:04:00 GMT
Content-Length:  0
```